# Running order of compiled express.js files?

Tags: node.js, express, babeljs

I have express.js application generated by express-generator. When I compile the app with Babel and run the execution order of files confused me.

The starting point of my application is /bin/www file but when I start the application other files running before the /bin/www file. My running scrips are like below and I am also sharing the directory order.

```
"start": "yarn prod",
"build": "yarn clean && yarn transpile",
"server": "node ./dist-server/bin/www",
"dev": "NODE_ENV=development yarn build && yarn server",
"prod": "NODE_ENV=production yarn build && yarn server",
"transpile": "babel ./server --out-dir dist-server",
"clean": "rimraf dist-server",
"watch:dev": "nodemon",
"test": "jest"
```

[Directory and file orders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7ZQc.png)

www.js file start like below code

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
console.log(1)
import app from "../app";
import debugLib from "debug";
import http from "http";
import ioLib from "socket.io";
import { socketInit } from "../sockets/training";
import connectDB from "../helpers/dbConnection";
```

And dbConnection.js file start like below:

```
console.log(2)
import r from "rethinkdb";
```

But when I start the compiled app the output is:

```
yarn run v1.22.5
$ NODE_ENV=development yarn build && yarn server
$ yarn clean && yarn transpile
$ rimraf dist-server
$ babel ./server --out-dir dist-server
Successfully compiled 10 files with Babel (1381ms).
$ node ./dist-server/bin/www
2
1
```

**Why it prints out 2 before 1?**

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that Babel compiles the below code:

```
console.log(1)
import app from "../app";
```

like this:

```
var _app = _interopRequireDefault(require("../app"));
console.log(1)
```

**So the parent class first imports the child classes, execute them then execute itself.**